# Building old version of Intel i40e driver on centOS errors

Tags: linux, centos, driver, linux-device-driver, intel

I'm trying to build an old version of the i40e driver for the Intel X710 NIC.
I have to use an old version of the driver because they removed a functionality I need. 
The version I'm trying to use is i40e-1.5.23 from 10/5/2016.
If I try to build the latest version, I don't get any errors.

I have installed "Development Tools" packages so Kernel-Devel, gcc...
My current Kernel version is 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
My current CentOS version is 7.4.1708

I tried with different kernel/kernel header versions but still get the same error. I also tried with various version of the i40e driver.

In the readme of the driver it's written that the kernel and kernel header files must be the same version and I'm quite sure they are in my situation.

Here is the output when I try to make in the src folder of the driver :

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.o
In file included from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e.h:51:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:25:
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/kcompat.h:5097:20: error: redefinition of ‘csum_replace_by_diff’
 static inline void csum_replace_by_diff(__sum16 *sum, __wsum diff)
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/skbuff.h:30:0,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/tcp.h:21,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/tcp.h:24,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e.h:27,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:25:
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/checksum.h:110:20: note: previous definition of ‘csum_replace_by_diff’ was here
 static inline void csum_replace_by_diff(__sum16 *sum, __wsum diff)
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e.h:51:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:25:
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/kcompat.h:5131:1: error: redefinition of ‘pci_request_io_regions’
 pci_request_io_regions(struct pci_dev *pdev, const char *name)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e.h:32:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:25:
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/pci.h:1425:1: note: previous definition of ‘pci_request_io_regions’ was here
 pci_request_io_regions(struct pci_dev *pdev, const char *name)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e.h:51:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:25:
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/kcompat.h:5138:1: error: redefinition of ‘pci_release_io_regions’
 pci_release_io_regions(struct pci_dev *pdev)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e.h:32:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:25:
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/pci.h:1432:1: note: previous definition of ‘pci_release_io_regions’ was here
 pci_release_io_regions(struct pci_dev *pdev)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e.h:51:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:25:
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/kcompat.h:5145:1: error: redefinition of ‘pci_request_mem_regions’
 pci_request_mem_regions(struct pci_dev *pdev, const char *name)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e.h:32:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:25:
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/pci.h:1439:1: note: previous definition of ‘pci_request_mem_regions’ was here
 pci_request_mem_regions(struct pci_dev *pdev, const char *name)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e.h:51:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:25:
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/kcompat.h:5152:1: error: redefinition of ‘pci_release_mem_regions’
 pci_release_mem_regions(struct pci_dev *pdev)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e.h:32:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:25:
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/pci.h:1446:1: note: previous definition of ‘pci_release_mem_regions’ was here
 pci_release_mem_regions(struct pci_dev *pdev)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/vxlan.h:5:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:30:
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/udp_tunnel.h:103:6: error: nested redefinition of ‘enum udp_parsable_tunnel_type’
 enum udp_parsable_tunnel_type {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/udp_tunnel.h:103:6: error: redeclaration of ‘enum udp_parsable_tunnel_type’
In file included from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e.h:51:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:25:
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/kcompat.h:5120:6: note: originally defined here
 enum udp_parsable_tunnel_type {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/vxlan.h:5:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:30:
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/udp_tunnel.h:104:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘UDP_TUNNEL_TYPE_VXLAN’
  UDP_TUNNEL_TYPE_VXLAN,  /* RFC 7348 */
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e.h:51:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:25:
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/kcompat.h:5121:2: note: previous definition of ‘UDP_TUNNEL_TYPE_VXLAN’ was here
  UDP_TUNNEL_TYPE_VXLAN,
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/vxlan.h:5:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:30:
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/udp_tunnel.h:105:2: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘UDP_TUNNEL_TYPE_GENEVE’
  UDP_TUNNEL_TYPE_GENEVE,  /* draft-ietf-nvo3-geneve */
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e.h:51:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:25:
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/kcompat.h:5122:2: note: previous definition of ‘UDP_TUNNEL_TYPE_GENEVE’ was here
  UDP_TUNNEL_TYPE_GENEVE,
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/vxlan.h:5:0,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:30:
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/udp_tunnel.h:109:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct udp_tunnel_info’
 struct udp_tunnel_info {
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/sock.h:51:0,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/tcp.h:23,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/tcp.h:24,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e.h:27,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:25:
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/netdevice.h:67:8: note: originally defined here
 struct udp_tunnel_info;
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c: In function ‘i40e_tx_timeout’:
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:281:42: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘trans_start’; did you mean ‘mem_start’?
   trans_start = q->trans_start ? : netdev->trans_start;
                                          ^~
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c: In function ‘i40e_ndo_bridge_getlink’:
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:9442:9: error: too few arguments to function ‘ndo_dflt_bridge_getlink’
  return ndo_dflt_bridge_getlink(skb, pid, seq, dev, veb->bridge_mode,
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/dst.h:13:0,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/sock.h:72,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/tcp.h:23,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/net/tcp.h:24,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e.h:27,
                 from /home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:25:
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux/rtnetlink.h:115:12: note: declared here
 extern int ndo_dflt_bridge_getlink(struct sk_buff *skb, u32 pid, u32 seq,
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c: At top level:
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:9494:2: error: unknown field ‘ndo_set_vf_vlan’ specified in initializer
  .ndo_set_vf_vlan = i40e_ndo_set_vf_port_vlan,
  ^
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c: In function ‘i40e_ndo_bridge_getlink’:
/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.c:9451:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/scripts/Makefile.build:341: recipe for target '/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.o' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src/i40e_main.o] Error 1
/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64/Makefile:1305: recipe for target '_module_/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src' failed
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/fla/Desktop/i40e-1.5.23/src] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64'
Makefile:96: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

It looks like the error is comming from kcompat.h.

I can't find any information on how to solve this problem elsewhere so that's why I created this post.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That driver version is probably still years newer than Linux 3.10 (released in 2013: https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.10).  Sounds like you need to *backport* the driver to your old kernel.  (I'm sure CentOS's Linux 3.10 has many patches newer than vanilla 3.10 when it was first released, but probably mostly security updates and not changes to the PCI infrastructure that your driver source was expecting).

Comment: Totally guessing, but the `i40e` driver defines `pci_request_mem_regions(struct pci_dev *pdev, const char *name)` in `kcompat.h`, so maybe your driver is expecting a newer kernel that no longer has that function itself?  Or an older kernel that doesn't have it?  Check if there's a `#ifdef` around that definition to enable it for certain kernel versions.

Comment: The kernel 3.10.0-514.e17 compiled the version 1.5.23.. magic.

Comment: It's obviously not magic; looks like my guess was right and that an older CentOS kernel doesn't have the patches that are incompatible with the driver.  StackOverflow is a site for actual programming questions, not for magic incantations that make things compile for unknown reasons.

Comment: relax dude. And thank you